# Returning Template from function

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

I am trying to return a pointer to a template from a function, however I am given the error:

```
error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'node<T>*' to 'Customer*'
```

Which is strange, because I know that the template is definitely holding a customer object.

The class that returns the error is this:

```
template <class T>
T* l_list<T>::search(int id)
{
    int i = 0;
    node<T> *ptr = head;
    while (id != ptr -> data.getId())
    {
        ptr = ptr -> next;
        i++;

        if (id = ptr -> data.getId())
        {
            return ptr;
        }
    }
}
```

and I call it by doing this:

```
cin >> id;
Customer* ptr = customers.search(id);
ptr -> createAccount();
```

Is it even possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is declared of type:

```
T*
```

But you are returning a type of:

```
node<T>*
```

You need to keep your return type consistent with your function type.

Answer (score 1):

The function `search` is declared to return `T*`, but you execute `return ptr;`, where `ptr` is a `node<T>*`. That can't work. Perhaps you wanted something like `return ptr->data;`?

Comment: Thanks, that fixed that error, but that line complains that I cannot convert 'Customer to 'Customer*'

Comment: @user1864298, return &ptr->data